# Is it possible to use armadillo to find integer solutions to a linear system?

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra, armadillo

I need to use armadillo to find integer solutions to a matrix of the form `Ax = 0`. Currently I'm using the `null` function to calculate a basis for the null space of A, but most of the time the basis generated does not consist of integer elements. The algorithm does not need to be very efficient, the operation only needs to happen once for a relatively small matrix. I could implement my own algorithm to find integer solutions from the basis generated by `null`, but I wanted to know if armadillo directly supported this. Thank you.

Edit: I'm using armadillo version 6.500.5.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no built-in method for this as this problem is not that easy. What is known about A? Continuous values? Then i would tackle it with [Mixed-integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). Integer values? Then it might be better to tackle it as a [system of linear diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#System_of_linear_Diophantine_equations). And what would be you own algorithm like? Which guarantees it would give? Of course one could always round the continuous solution, but the error would be possibly huge.

Comment: Linear Diophantine equations look promising, I will look into that. `A` consists of integer values. My problem mathematically guarantees that some null space basis (aka some multiple of the solution `X`) should consist of all positive integer values so my solution would involve trying a bunch of integer multiples of `X`. Thanks though!

Comment: I think i would try the MIP-approach first, because there is some quality software there. It should be easy to add [cbc](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc) to your project and formulate your equation there.